# How to allow user to add information for every fields in forms

Tags: user-interface, database-design

i have a strange user request: they want to be able to say for every fields in every forms from where they get information used to compile it.

value must be selected from a list

essentially iam looking a way to avoid to double the fields.

one way can be add a M:M table where link field-name and information-source

but using this for retrive from real data table only fields derived from an info-source can be really bad

**EDIT**

to be more clear the solution i want to avoid is to have a data table like this:

```
fieldname1
fieldname1Origin
fieldname2
fieldname2Origin
fieldname3
fieldname3Origin
...
```

but i do the link table in this way:

```
FieldName
OriginId
```

i have to map oll field names and to search in it with string name when i need to query data table i have to do something like this

```
select 
case when (exists select 1 from LinkTable where FieldName='fieldname1' AND
           OriginId=SelectedID) then fieldname1
else NULL
end
```

for every fields

Comment: Are you saying your users want to store the origin of each *value* in each *row*? For example, do they want to say that Fred's phone number is "123-456-7890", and it came from company letterhead, while Barney's phone number is "234-567-8901", and it came from email from Barney?

Comment: exaclty, i try to dissuade them but without success

Comment: So every update to phone numbers must also update the origin. (Did they think about that?)

Comment: yes, the will first insert info by their own, distinguishing reliable information from those uncertain, next they want to extract all uncertain info, discuss them with other people, than editing values (and origin too). this process can be done multiple times for each record (but luckily they want to storage only last one and not all passages)

Answer (score 0):

What about mixing several controls, such as a combobox with all lines, that would trigger the display of all columns of that line.

Something like that (I am currenlty working on that project):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to really understand your needs well. So what I will propose may be irrelevant, but you could just add a small button that would open a "details" popup with the origin. Your edit actually just confused me lol

Comment: ui is my last problem, the data model is real drama. little more example: user have to fill process type - they also want to save where they found that info (they know on their own, they ask support, they search on rules book...) and want to do that for every field thet have to compile